# How to select date every 2 weeks for a date picker

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, it selects every Monday(every 2 weeks) for a date picker, this code is works for me, is there a simple way to auto select the dates instead of manually write the date for each day?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {

 if ( formId == 3 && fieldId == 45 ) {
 optionsObj.minDate = 0;
 optionsObj.beforeShowDay = function(date) {
            var enabledDays = ['05/22/2023', '06/05/2023', '06/19/2023', '07/03/2023', '07/17/2023', '08/14/2023', '08/28/2023', '09/11/2023', '09/25/2023', '10/09/2023'],
                currentDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date),
                day = date.getDay();
  
            return [(enabledDays.indexOf(currentDate) != -1)];
        };
 }
 return optionsObj;
 } );

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the option an array as a value

```js
console.log(value[0]) // will return 1
console.log(value[3]) // will return 4
console.log(value) // will return [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

```html
<select name="weekly_date" id="weekly_date_value" onChange="SetFieldProperty('rdaWeeklyDateGField', this.value);">
  <option value="">Choose Day</option>
  <option value="0">Sunday</option>
  <option value="1">Monday</option>
  <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="4">Thursday</option>
  <option value="5">Friday</option>
  <option value="6">Saturday</option>
  <option value="[1,2,3,4,5,6]">except sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, anyway, I have no idea, why it is not working, I think the related code for js is this one, do you have any idea?
`                 
if (ajaxdata["rdaWeeklyDateGField"]) {
                        optionsObj.beforeShowDay = function (date) {
                            var day = date.getDay();
                            return [day != ajaxdata["rdaWeeklyDateGField"]];
                        };
`

Comment: I made a snippet. Your code does not make any sense

Comment: Thank you, I have found another way, I have modified the question, can you review the question again? do you have any idea for this?